# Xeon X3430 usable memory limit

Tags: memory, windows-server-2008-r2, xeon

I Installed new 4x8GB RAM chips on my Xeon X3430 that's uses Windows server 2008 r2 standard, although 32GB is shown only 16GB is usable, why?

Comment: At boot time, is the Bios reports 32GB RAM installed ?

Comment: Which motherboard? Check which slots you have the RAM in. Some (dual-CPU) motherboards require a second CPU for half the slots to work.

Comment: @Bob Windows reports 32GB so I guess the BIOS does as well, no?
As for dual-CPU if that were the case then my previous setup of 4x2GB would have shown 4GB usable, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be happening for a couple of reasons.

First, make sure that the BIOS is up to date, it may limit the amount of RAM that is usable.  If 16GB was the max available when that version of the BIOS was released it could impact the system.

Second, as mentioned by Bob, if this is a dual socket motherboard, it may be required that both sockets are filled before the motherboard will recognize all the RAM.

Check the motherboard manual and make sure that 32GB of RAM is supported.

Comment: Turns out it was the motherboard Dell T110 does not support 32GB

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the motherboard Dell T110 does not support 32GB